# Does [tag:death-star] include this other structure?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Of course, I mean

> Starkiller Base from *Star Wars VII: The Force Awakens*

Should it be included (should the tag description be amended)?   Should there be a tag synonym?  Should there be a new tag?

Comment: On the one hand no, on the other hand yes, and in the gripping hand... maybe.

Answer (score 6):

[starkiller-base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starkiller-base) is not justified at this time.   No action is needed.

Arguments:

- Starkiller Base is not a Death Star (is it not named as such)
- Users won't expect Starkiller Base to be included in [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star)
- [starkiller-base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starkiller-base) is not justified at this time by usual tag creation metrics

Comment: Why?  Add some reasoning.

Comment: @Keen, I'm just offering the three alternatives for voting and discussion purposes.   I'm not voting.

Comment: Discussion is more effective when there's more than one person, and they're providing varying viewpoints.  Posting a poll like this is less effective.

Comment: @Keen:  I've added the arguments as I see them, but everyone else should feel free to add arguments at will.

Comment: *"it's another Death Star"*

Comment: @Richard:  If you are supporting this option, does it mean to think people should be using [tag:death-star] for Starkiller Base, **and** you **don't** this the synonym is justified?   What would be the harm of a synonym?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I neither support, nor oppose this proposition. I was merely pointing out what's said in the script.

Answer (score -1):

We should create [starkiller-base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starkiller-base)

Arguments:

- Starkiller Base is not a Death Star (is it not named as such)
- Users won't expect Starkiller Base to be included in [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star)
- Starkiller Base is significant enough, and there are enough related question to support [starkiller-base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starkiller-base)
- If we don't do this, or make it a [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star) synonym some users are likely to use [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star) any for Starkiller Base anyhow.

Answer (score -6):

[starkiller-base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starkiller-base) should be a synonym of [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star)

Arguments:

- Starkiller Base is essentially an amped up Death Star
- There were already two Death Stars, so the existing tag already comprises more than one entity
- Some people may be surprised to include Starkiller Base in [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star) because the name differs, therefore it makes sense to make a tag synonym
- For example, this question: [Why does The Dark Side keep building Death Stars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112753/why-does-the-dark-side-keep-building-death-stars) seems assume that "Death Star" includes Starkiller Base.
- If we don't do this, or create [starkiller-base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starkiller-base) some users are likely to use [death-star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-star) for Starkiller Base anyhow.